# jQuery cookie, when I press F5, I can't watch the options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a problem with the cookies. I'm trying to store the options selected in cookies. But I don't understand why my example is not working.

For example, the font size is not remembered. It´s the first time that I'm using [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

HTML (in the first select, the options content images to change the background):

```
<h3>Seleccione un fondo de imagen</h3>
<select name="foo" id="foo" size="2">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    <option value="4"></option>
    <option value="5"></option>
    <option value="6"></option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Establecer fondo" />

<h3>Seleccione una fuente</h3>
<select name="fuente" id="fuente" size="2" style='-moz-border-radius: 8px;'>
    <option value="1">Arial</option>
    <option value="2">Tahoma</option>
    <option value="3">Verdana</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Establecer fuente" />

<h3>Seleccione un tama&ntilde;o de fuente</h3>
<select name="fuentesize" id="fuentesize" size="2" style='-moz-border-radius: 8px;'>
    <option value="1">8</option>
    <option value="2">10</option>
    <option value="3">12</option>
    <option value="4">14</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Establecer tama&ntilde;o de fuente" />

<h3>Seleccione un color de fuente</h3>
<select name="fuentecolor" id="fuentecolor" size="2" style='-moz-border-radius: 8px;'>
    <option value="1">rojo</option>
    <option value="2">azul</option>
    <option value="3">verde</option>
    <option value="4">rosa</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button4" value="Establecer color de fuente" />

<h3>Seleccione un estilo para la fuente</h3>
<select name="fuentestilo" id="fuentestilo" size="2" style='-moz-border-radius: 8px;'>
    <option value="1">cursiva</option>
    <option value="2">subrayado</option>
    <option value="3">sin subrayado</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button5" value="Establecer estilo de fuente" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value;
    value = $.cookie("cookieFondo");
    if (value) {
        $("#foo").val(value);
    }
    value = $.cookie("cookieFuente");
    if (value) {
        $("#fuente").val(value);
    }
    var value;
    value = $.cookie("cookieFuenteSize");
    if (value) {
        $("#fuentesize").val(value);
    }
    value = $.cookie("cookieFuenteColor");
    if (value) {
        $("#fuentecolor").val(value);
    }
    value = $.cookie("cookieFuentEstilo");
    if (value) {
        $("#fuentestilo").val(value);
    }


    $('#button1').click(function() {
        //alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
        var bg = $('#foo').val();
        if(bg==1){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg00.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
        if(bg==2){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg01.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
        if(bg==3){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg02.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
        if(bg==4){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg03.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
        if(bg==5){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg04.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
        if(bg==6){
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/bg05.png)');
            $.cookie("cookieFondo", bg);
        }
    });


    $('#button2').click(function() {
        //alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
       var font = $('#fuente').val();
           if(font==1){
            $('body').css('font-family', 'Arial');
            $.cookie("cookieFuente", font);
        }
        if(font==2){
            $('body').css('font-family', 'Tahoma');
            $.cookie("cookieFuente", font);
        }
        if(font==3){
            $('body').css('font-family', 'Verdana');
            $.cookie("cookieFuente", font);
        }
    });

    $('#button3').click(function() {
        //alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
       var fontsize = $('#fuentesize').val();
           if(fontsize==1){
            $('body').css('font-size', 8);
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteSize", fontsize);
        }
        if(fontsize==2){
            $('body').css('font-size', 10);
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteSize", fontsize);
        }
        if(fontsize==3){
            $('body').css('font-size', 12);
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteSize", fontsize);
        }
        if(fontsize==4){
            $('body').css('font-size', 14);
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteSize", fontsize);
        }
    });

    $('#button4').click(function() {
        //alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
       var fontcolor = $('#fuentecolor').val();
           if(fontcolor==1){
            $('body').css('color', 'red');
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteColor", fontcolor);
        }
        if(fontcolor==2){
            $('body').css('color', 'blue');
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteColor", fontcolor);
        }
        if(fontcolor==3){
            $('body').css('color', 'green');
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteColor", fontcolor);
        }
        if(fontcolor==4){
            $('body').css('color', 'pink');
            $.cookie("cookieFuenteColor", fontcolor);
        }
    });

    $('#button5').click(function() {
        //alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
       var fontstyle = $('#fuentestilo').val();
           if(fontstyle==1){
            $('body').css('font-style', 'italic');
            $.cookie("cookieFuentEstilo", fontstyle);
        }
        if(fontstyle==2){
            $('body').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
            $.cookie("cookieFuentEstilo", fontstyle);
        }
        if(fontstyle==3){
            $('body').css('text-decoration' , 'none');
            $.cookie("cookieFuentEstilo", fontstyle);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving values into cookies, but when the page loads, you are not reading the cookies to initialize the state of your page from the values stored in the cookies.

You need to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value;
    value = $.cookie("cookieFondo");
    if (value) {
         $("#foo").val(value);
    }
    value = $.cookie("cookieFuente");
    if (value) {
         $("#fuente").val(value);
    }
    // ... more here
});
```

Or a more DRY version using a table would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value;
    var items = [
        "cookieFondo", "#foo",
        "cookieFuente", "#fuente"
        // list more items here
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=2) {
        value = $.cookie(items[i]);
        if (value) {
            $(items[i+1]).val(value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And if I wanted to reset the cookies? what is the best method?

Comment: That depends upon exactly what cookie library and version you are using.  With [this one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), you would use `$.removeCookie("cookieFondo")` and you would have to pass the same path you used when creating the cookie.  FYI, if you want to use these cookies anywhere on your site, you also may need to set the cookie path to `"/"`.

Comment: i used the first way that u added here, but it doesn´t work. What did i do bad?

Comment: @jal - you would have to show us a link to the actual page you put the code in for us to know what isn't correct.

Comment: @jal - the code I suggested initializes the select options correctly.  If you want to also initialize some page styles based on the cookie values, then you have to add that to the initialization code also based on what the cookie value is.